# How jersey generate the wadl, are there a scheme for this

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jersey, jersey-2.0

I want to parse a .wadl file which is generated by jersey. but I have no idea that how jersey generate the wadl file, and is there a scheme file used by jersey. In fact ,I want to find the scheme file and use xmlBeans to parse the wadl file. I want to know is there any other method to do this. I will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is look at the [resource class that generated the wadl response](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/wadl/internal/WadlResource.java#L74). You'll see that [model class it uses as the representation](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/wadl/internal/WadlResource.java#L113), is that [`com.sun.research.ws.wadl.Application`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/com/sun/research/ws/wadl/Application.java#L60), which is a JAXB generated class. If you look at the [containing package](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/core-server/src/main/java/com/sun/research/ws/wadl), you will see all the other model classes the make up the complete wadl model.

So since these are JAXB classes, you can just use JAXB to unmarshal the response using the `Application` class as the root model type.

If you are using the Jersey client, you could then unmarshal straight to `Application` from the `Response`

```
Response response = target("application.wadl").request("application/xml").get();
Application wadlApp = response.readEntity(Application.class);
```

Or if you get a `String` or `InputStream` some other way, you can use JAXB directly to unmarshal

```
String wadlString = ...
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Application.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Application wadlApp = (Application)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(wadlString));
```

The problem with this approach is that the classes are contained in the `jersey-server` artifact. You might not want this load for whatever you are doing.

You can also try to use [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) to generate the JAXB classes yourself, with the [wadl.xsd](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/etc/wadl.xsd) Jersey uses. I would imagine you get similar if not the same model classes used by Jersey. This way you don't need to depend on the `jersey-server`.

---

#### UPDATE

So I just tested with xjc to generate the JAXB classes, using the above wadl.xml, and it works. It produces the same classes used by Jersey

```
// maven directory structure (src/main/java)
xjc -d src/main/java -p com.stackoverflow.jersey.wadl.test wadl.xsd
```

Then you can just use the JAXB example above to unmarshal using the generated classes.